# Configure serial port for long commands

Tags: python, pyserial

Assume you try to interact with a shell via serial port. What happens when you hit the end of the line is that a `<space><carriage return>` gets inserted. This is already uncomfortable when using `screen` or `minicom` because it usually just continues writing on the same line (the linefeed is missing), but it results in buggy code when you need to parse the output stream. I am wondering how I can configure my serial connection to simply do nothing at the end of the line.

Example:

```
$ python -i -c "import serial; s=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB3', 115200, timeout=1.5)"
>>> s.write("echo \"123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123213\""); print s.readall().encode('string-escape')
211
echo "12312312312312312312312312312312312312312312312312312 \r31231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231231 \r23123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123213"
```

Solving this by changing the parser is not an option, because the parsing is done by a third party library in my case. Also just setting the line length to a very high number might work but is not what I like to do. I'd rather have control over the port's behaviour when the line is full.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that the problem has nothing to do with `pyserial`. If you send data with the `write` command to a serial port, it just sends the data to the serial port regardless of what you send (even binary data). The same applies to `read`.

So, the extra space and newline are inserted by the shell in the other end of the connection. There is probably no reasonable way around this problem without configuring the other end. For example, in Linux you might want to try `setterm -linewrap off` or just simply change the terminal width to be large enough wtih `stty`.

I think this question will receive more complete answers in https://unix.stackexchange.com/ if your remote terminal is a Unix/Linux.

Comment: No need for excuses, all you write is exactly what I want as a response! Yes, the problem occurs with other tools as well. I just added pyserial because it makes the problem more obvious. I think the setterm linewrap command might be exactly what will resolve this, sadly the server side doesn't have that tool installed. I see if I can find it. Thanks!